# Routing Error with Rails Admin and Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I am having issues getting Rails Admin to play nice with Heroku. I am getting a routing error when an admin is logged in, here is the error:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"rails_admin/main"}
```

I believe this error occurs because of this code in my `application.html.erb`:

```
<% if current_admin  %>
    <%= link_to "Admin Dashboard", rails_admin.index_path %>
<% end %>
```

It seems to occur when I call the `rails_admin.index_path` in the `link_to`. However if I go to `myurl/admin` it lets me see the admin dashboard fine. Also everything works fine in my development and production environment locally.

Output of `rake routes`:

```
             rails_admin        /admin                         RailsAdmin::Engine
             users_index GET    /users/index(.:format)         users#index
              users_show GET    /users/show(.:format)          users#show
                                /user/:id(.:format)            users#show
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
           welcome_index GET    /welcome/index(.:format)       welcome#index
                   songs GET    /songs(.:format)               songs#index
                         POST   /songs(.:format)               songs#create
                new_song GET    /songs/new(.:format)           songs#new
               edit_song GET    /songs/:id/edit(.:format)      songs#edit
                    song GET    /songs/:id(.:format)           songs#show
                         PUT    /songs/:id(.:format)           songs#update
                         DELETE /songs/:id(.:format)           songs#destroy
                    root        /                              welcome#index

Routes for RailsAdmin::Engine:
    dashboard GET         /                                      rails_admin/main#dashboard
        index GET|POST    /:model_name(.:format)                 rails_admin/main#index
          new GET|POST    /:model_name/new(.:format)             rails_admin/main#new
       export GET|POST    /:model_name/export(.:format)          rails_admin/main#export
  bulk_delete POST|DELETE /:model_name/bulk_delete(.:format)     rails_admin/main#bulk_delete
history_index GET         /:model_name/history(.:format)         rails_admin/main#history_index
  bulk_action POST        /:model_name/bulk_action(.:format)     rails_admin/main#bulk_action
         show GET         /:model_name/:id(.:format)             rails_admin/main#show
         edit GET|PUT     /:model_name/:id/edit(.:format)        rails_admin/main#edit
       delete GET|DELETE  /:model_name/:id/delete(.:format)      rails_admin/main#delete
 history_show GET         /:model_name/:id/history(.:format)     rails_admin/main#history_show
  show_in_app GET         /:model_name/:id/show_in_app(.:format) rails_admin/main#show_in_app
```

Comment: What is the output of `rake routes`?

Comment: Here is the output http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=VRPcgXPJ

Comment: There's really no need to use pastebin. It just means clicking on a another link and provides no additional functionality than having the code here. And it's possible the link will be dead in the future.

Comment: oh ok. I'll do that in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for me was to change

```
rails_admin.index_path
```

to

```
rails_admin.dashboard_path
```

Don't know why it doesn't work the other way around in production but this will do.

Comment: rails_admin.index_path is a collection level route and you need to set a model name, I don't know why it worked locally..

Comment: @BenoitB. Can you explain what you mean by "collection level" route? or point me to a resource that explains it. Also what do you mean I need to set a model name. Still learning Rails, trying to understand everything that is going on.

Comment: Index path needs a model for RailsAdmin: it's the index page of a model. Index is called a collection action in RailsAdmin (it applies to a collection of record). What you were looking for was the path to the dashboard, hence dashboard_path. You can have a look at RailsAdmin routing there: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/config/routes.rb#L5